# При миграции PоstgreSQL в Django выдает ошибку пользователь не прошёл проверку подлинности (Peer)

Tags: django, postgresql

ОС Ubuntu. Хочу перенести данные из sqlite в postgresql. Выполнил следующие действия в терминале:

1. `sudo -i -u postgres`
2. `psql`
3. Создал пользователя `blog` с паролем: `CREATE USER blog WITH PASSWORD 'qwerty';` Успешно.
4. Дал пользователю `blog` права superuser: `ALTER USER blog WITH SUPERUSER;` Успешно.
5. Создал базу данных `blog`: `CREATE DATABASE blog OWNER blog ENCODING 'UTF8';` Успешно.
6. Выгрузил существующие данные: `python manage.py dumpdata --indent=2 --output=mysite_data.json`. Успешно
7. Изменил в `settings.py`

   ```
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
           'NAME': 'blog',
           'USER': 'blog',
           'PASSWORD': 'qwerty',
       }
   }
   ```
8. при выполнении `python manage.py migrate` выдает ошибку:

   > django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: ВАЖНО: пользователь "blog" не прошёл проверку подлинности (Peer)

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Так же если решение ниже не исправит проблему, возможно что-то не так с постгрей

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить  'HOST': 'localhost' в settings для вашей БД, HOST обязательно нужно указать, порт можете не указывать если он 5432 - это значение по умолчанию

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: Что-то не так? @wchistow

Comment: Желательно написать куда это надо добавить и почему.

Comment: @wchistow понял, допишу, мне казалось там и так все понятно